# XML view: How to bind two different paths to one element?

Tags: xml, data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am developing Fiori App to display some sales data, called from an OData Service. I have a header (invoiceHeaderSet) with the field "Waerk" to display the currency key.

I have positions (/invoiceHeaderPositionsNav) bound to a table. Now, I want to display the headers "Waerk" field next to each positions currency field "Netwr".

How can I do this in XML views without creating surplus local models? Below, you will see a **simplified** example of my problem.

```
// this view is bound to OData /invoiceHeaderSet
<ObjectHeader
    numberUnit="{Waerk}"/> <-- does work
   <Table
     items="{
       path: 'invoiceHeaderPositionsNav'
         }" />
      <ColumnListItem 
         <Text text="{'Netwr'} <-- does work
                     {'/invoiceHeaderSet/Waerk'}"/> <-- does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution A**

Did you activate the complex binding syntax in the bootstrapping part of your index.html?

```
data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

**Solution B**

What you could also do is writing your own formatter method. For that you have to change your binding to something like this:

```
text="{ parts: [{ path: 'Netwr' }, { path: '/invoiceHeaderSet/Waerk' }], formatter: '.formatTitle' }"
```

And in your Controller you have to implement the `formatTitle` function, e. g.

```
formatTitle: function (sNetwr, sWaerk) {
    return sNetwr + " " + sWaerk;
},
```

Comment: I am sorry if I mislead you, but '/invoiceHeaderSet/Waerk' was just a lucky guess. Are you sure, this would work?

Comment: I thought your problem was to bind more than one path to a single element. My solution helps with that problem. If your problem is to access a specific path of your model, then you should show us your model (some json) and rephrase your question.